# ESPACIOS EN BLANCO EN SQL SERVER proyecto con C#

Tags: c#, sql

Hola recientemente estoy trabajando sobre un proyecto con c# y quisiera saber como podría guardar un dato en la base de datos(sqlserver) con espacios en blanco hacia la izquierda por ejemplo,
que en la tabla pesos, el cod_peso que es de 5 caracteres y yo ingreso 3 se guarde de la siguiente manera:

'  444'

He intentado sacando el largo del campo:

```
SELECT COL_LENGTH('pesos', 'cod_peso') largo;
```

Comment: Por qué quieres guardar más datos de los necesarios? Eso parece más un detalle de formato que algo que se requiera guardar.

Comment: Es lo que se me pidió por parte del cliente

Comment: Explícale al cliente que eso le va a costar más dinero en almacenamiento y tráfico de red.

Comment: necesitan tener completo los campos de cada registro, por eso la necesidad de llenar con espacios en blanco hacia la izquierda, por eso me interesa saber como puedo agregar esa condicion

Comment: Cuando alguien pide algo asi.. es porque hay algo que esta muy raro en algun lado.. mas alla de eso.. tu problema es al guardarlo? si es asi, que tiene que ver el select... tendriamos que ver como lo guardas....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comparto las inquietudes planteadas en los comentarios. ya que no deberían guardarse valores de estar forma. aun así entiendo que por fuerza mayor podría requerirse, con este código puedes agregar ' ' en la izquierda hasta completar el largo 5.

```
DECLARE @texto VARCHAR(5) = '444'
SELECT RIGHT('     ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @texto), 5)
```

personalmente guardaría el campo sin los espacios y al momento de consultarlo lo haría con el código que acabo de compartir.

Espero que mi respuesta sea de tu ayuda.